# How to set custom 403 response in OAuth2 resource server?

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

**Spring boot 2.4.3**
If the user has no permission for action, it gives 403 response but without any response body. However the header `WWW-Authenticate` is set:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="insufficient_scope", error_description="The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token."
```

I would like still to have some response body with message. How could I achieve it?

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/app/**", "/admin/**").authenticated()
                        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/app/**", "/admin/**").authenticated()
                        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/app/**", "/admin/**").authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the following solution:

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();

        response.setStatus(...);
        response.setContentType(...);
        response.getWriter().write("your custom error response");
    }
}
```

Then in your security config:

```java
http. 
  //...
    .oauth2ResourceServer()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint())
```

Comment: Returning OK status? :)

Comment: Updated it. In my use case I was returning a GraphQL error which was intended to always return 200 Ok.